# Installation steps for xenomai 3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, xenomai

I would like to install Xenomai 3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I wan unable to find any proper installation guide/procedure for the same.

Request help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes on Installing the Cobalt core

1) Download Ubuntu 16.04.1 (v4.4 kernel)
    from: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/

```
Install on USB drive using: Universal USB Installer
```

2) Download: linux-4.4.43.tar.gz

```
from: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/
```

3) Download: xenomai-3.0.3.tar.bz2

```
from: https://xenomai.org/downloads/xenomai/stable/latest/

Unzip to /usr/src
```

4) Download: ipipe-core-4.4.43-x86-6.patch

```
from: https://xenomai.org/downloads/ipipe/v4.x/x86/
```

5) Run these commands

```
apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5-dev build-essential kernel-package fakeroot libssl-dev
```

6) Prepare the Cobalt kernel

```
    cd /usr/src/linux-4.4.43

    /usr/src/xenomai-3.0.3/scripts/prepare-kernel.sh --arch=x86_64 --linux=/usr/src/linux-4.4.43 --ipipe=/usr/src/ipipe-core-4.4.43-x86-6.patch
```

7) Run
    cd /usr/src/linux-4.4.43
    cp /boot/config-4.4.0-31-generic .config

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib/pkgconfig
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Qt/5.8/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

make [ARCH=i386] xconfig
```

8) Apply Settings from: https://xenomai.org//2014/06/configuring-for-x86-based-dual-kernels/#Optimized_CPU_and_platform_settings

```
    Power Management and ACPI options->ACPI Support
    Search for ACPI_PROCESSOR (disable ACPI_PROCESSOR)
    Search for CPU_FREQ (disable CPU frequency scaling)
    Search for CPU_IDLE (disable CPU idle PM support)
    Search for INTEL_IDLE (disable)
    Search for INPUT_PCSPKR (disable PC speaker support)


    Search for XENO and enable RTnet
        Yes -   Enable RTnet, TCP/IP socket interface
        Yes -   Search for XENO and enable User-space device driver framework

    Search for UNISYS (disable Unisys SPAR driver support)
```

9) Run

```
export CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=4
make bzImage modules

make modules_install
make install
```

10) Install Xenomai

```
./configure --with-core=cobalt --enable-smp --enable-pshared
make install
```

Comment: where can i find detailed tutorial for this?